# React Route Redirect to the correct path but not loading the content

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React Route Redirect to the correct path but not loading the content of the page...after refreshing the page its loading the content. But I want the page should load the content immediately after redirect not after refreshing the page

```
 <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/dashboard" Component={dashboard} />
                <Route exact path="/" Component={dashboard} />
                <Route exact path="/logout" Component={login} />
                <Route exact path="/categories" Component={dashboard} /
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share your code or a minimal example of the issue?

Comment: @MehmetSeckin : I have a login page after the login success should redirect to a dashboard page                                                                                                         <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={dashboard} />
                    <Route exact path="/" component={dashboard} />

Comment: I could redirect to the dashboard page but the contents are not loading once i refreshing my page then i am getting

Comment: Hi Ramya, thanks for posting this. Please edit your question and add the relevant code, so we can have a look and try to find the issue.

Comment: Edited.. You got it right?? url changed in browser but page content not loading

Comment: Hi Ramya, could you post a larger code snippet or an example that reproduces this issue? It should include the entire Router structure and the component in which it is implemented.